# How do I license the data visualization components (charting) for the Flex SDK on an automated builder server?

Tags: licensing, automation, flexbuilder, apache-flex

I have a professional license of Flex 3.3.  This allows me to create applications using the data visualization components (charts) without watermarks.  However, all of release builds (test, production, etc) occur on our build server.

The build server only has the Flex SDK installed (not full Flex Builder). As a result the SWFs compiled with this SDK contain watermarks on all the charts.  How can I apply a Flex Builder Professional license to the build server to remove the watermakrs w/o installing Flex Builder?

My build environment is Flex SDK 3.3 + CruiseControl.NET + NAnt.

Comment: How can this work for Flashbuilder4? All I see are examples for FB3, but what about FB4??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a bit of Google searching (more than usual) but I was able to find [the answer.](http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/how-to-apply-the-data-visualization-license-on-command-line-in-flex-3/) I needed to apply the Flex Builder Pro product name and serial number to the a flex-config.xml file in the /frameworks/ directory like so:

```
<licenses>
   <license>
      <product>flexbuilder3</product>
      <serial-number>your serial number here</serial-number>
   </license>
</licenses>
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works for any build environment, be it NAnt, Ant,  or any other setup.

Comment: How does this work for Flashbuilder 4? All I see are FB3 examples??

Answer (score 0):

Came across same issue, but trying to use mxmlc commandline with the mxmlc -licenses.license option complained... the following worked though:

```
mxmlc -license=flexbuilder3,"XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"
```